# How to Track Min and Max Balance of an Account

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am looking at tracking the maximum and minimum balance of a banking account. There are two tables:

AccountBalanceHistoryTable - this records the balance for each account at the end of each month

TransactionTable - this records all the transactions that take place on an account

I have created the following query to bring these two tables together to get a running balance, which I will then use to select the max and min balances from:

```
select
    i.acct_id,
    i.trnxamt,
    i.date_trnx,
    EXTRACT (MONTH from i.date_trnx) month_num,
    EXTRACT (YEAR from i.date_trnx) as year_num,
    (
        j.balance + sum(i.trnxamt) over (partition by i.acct_id order by i.date_trnx ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
    ) as balance_calc
from
    TransactionTable i
    left join (
        select
            acct_id,
            monthend_date,
            balance,
            row_number() over (partition by acct_id order by monthend_date) as rn
        from
            AccountBalanceHistoryTable
    ) j on i.acct_id = j.acct_id
    and j.rn = 1
```

I use the AccountBalanceHistoryTable to get the last balance I see recorded for a month (first row) and make that my starting balance for the next month.

So let's say in the AccountBalanceHistoryTable shows that for account 123456, there is a balance of $100 for August 31st. The following just shows some sample transactions and what the Balance_Calc would calculate:

| Acct_ID | TrnxAmnt | Date_Trnx | Month_num | Year_num | Balance_Calc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | -55 | 29-Sep-20 | 9 | 2020 | 45 |
| 123456 | 10 | 30-Sep-20 | 9 | 2020 | 55 |
| 123456 | 100 | 1-Oct-20 | 10 | 2020 | 155 |
| 123456 | 20 | 1-Oct-20 | 10 | 2020 | 175 |

The problem I have is, say for October 1st above. Before any transactions occur on this account for October, the opening balance is $55 (the closing balance of September 30). This $55 should actually be my min balance for October but if I take the table above and select the Min and Max balance for October 2020, it's going to give me a min balance of $155 and a Max Balance of $175 since those are the only two records showing in the above subquery results.

Comment: General question to begin with: Do you actually need to even look at the monthly closing balances table? Can't those be computed from the transactions table anyway? If that is so, it may be much easier (and more efficient) to do all the computations based just on the transactions table. I can show you how (many people can show you how), but first please confirm that this is in fact correct.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber - that's why I asked. At least in "advanced" countries, at "reputable" banks, a complete history of transactions from the beginning of an account is routinely preserved, even if in a data warehouse computations are often based on last month's closing balance. If the OP needs to look at individual transactions anyway though (as he must, for his task), this means he **must** look at individual transactions. Alternatively, we need **one** opening balance per account, not every monthly opening balance.

Comment: Another question for clarification. Your data only shows transaction date (no time-of-day component). Is that correct, or are the transactions recorded with time-of-day? Either way - can two transactions occur AT THE SAME TIME? and if so, how do you handle that for computing balances? Unless you aggregate them before computing a new balance, you will have ambiguities. For example, deposit 30 and withdraw 20 in the same transaction (same timestamp) - is that shown as a single deposit of 10? If not, do you compute the rolling balance by adding 30 first, or subtracting 20 first?

Comment: @Marmite Bomber - this works perfectly - thanks so much. Just for my own learning, what's the benefit of using the "With" statement? From what I can tell it just makes the query a bit simpler? I suppose the same thing could be done with separate select statements and then a union between the two (i.e. one for the balance history and one for the transactions)?

Comment: @Marmite Bomber - Also - I think I understand what the decode statement is being used for - basically to assign the record from the AccountBalanceHistoryTable a "1" and the record from the TransactionTable a "2" for ordering purposes in case there is a transaction on the exact same day as the balance history? I should have mentioned that the date of transaction typically has a time stamp associated with it but I am glad this works in general anyways. Thanks again!

Comment: @Jonathan `with x as (subquery1) select * from x` is the same as `select * from (subquery1)`. `WITH` is often used is you have more cascading subqueries. Simple check examples in the documenration. The ordering on `source` is to enforce that event if you have same timestamp in the balance row and in the transaction row, the balance record will be considered first. You are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to *shift* the *month end* balance over midnight to the 1st of the next month.

Here is the example of the *balance* table

```
select * from AccountBalanceHistory
where acct_id = 123456 
order by monthend_date;

   ACCT_ID MONTHEND_DATE          BALANCE
---------- ------------------- ----------
    123456 31.08.2020 00:00:00        100
    123456 30.09.2020 00:00:00         55
    123456 31.10.2020 00:00:00        175
```

and your transaction table

```
select * from Transaction
where acct_id = 123456 
order by date_trnx;

   ACCT_ID DATE_TRNX              TRNXAMT
---------- ------------------- ----------
    123456 29.09.2020 00:00:00        -55
    123456 30.09.2020 00:00:00         10
    123456 01.10.2020 00:00:00        100
    123456 01.10.2020 00:00:00         20
```

The query below *unions* the both sources and calculate the *trasnaction month*, which is for the balance the *1st of the next month*.

Note that each row has it source BAL or TX - this will be used to *order* the rows correctly

```
with tx as (
select 'BAL' source, acct_id,  monthend_date  date_trnx, trunc(monthend_date+1,'MM') tx_month, balance, 0 trnxamt from AccountBalanceHistory
union all
select 'TX', acct_id, date_trnx,trunc(date_trnx,'MM') tx_month, trnxamt balance, trnxamt from Transaction
)
select *
from tx
where acct_id = 123456 
order by date_trnx;

SOU    ACCT_ID DATE_TRNX           TX_MONTH               BALANCE    TRNXAMT
--- ---------- ------------------- ------------------- ---------- ----------
BAL     123456 31.08.2020 00:00:00 01.09.2020 00:00:00        100          0
TX      123456 29.09.2020 00:00:00 01.09.2020 00:00:00        -55        -55
TX      123456 30.09.2020 00:00:00 01.09.2020 00:00:00         10         10
BAL     123456 30.09.2020 00:00:00 01.10.2020 00:00:00         55          0
TX      123456 01.10.2020 00:00:00 01.10.2020 00:00:00         20         20
TX      123456 01.10.2020 00:00:00 01.10.2020 00:00:00        100        100
BAL     123456 31.10.2020 00:00:00 01.11.2020 00:00:00        175          0
```

The column `balance` contains either the balance or the transaction amount and is not very interesting until we add it
using analytical windowing function  for each month (from the begining of the month to the current row)

```
with tx as (
select 'BAL' source, acct_id,  monthend_date  date_trnx, trunc(monthend_date+1,'MM') tx_month, balance, 0 trnxamt from AccountBalanceHistory
union all
select 'TX', acct_id, date_trnx,trunc(date_trnx,'MM') tx_month, trnxamt balance, trnxamt from Transaction
)
select 
SOURCE, ACCT_ID, DATE_TRNX, TX_MONTH,  
sum(BALANCE) over (partition by ACCT_ID,TX_MONTH order by date_trnx, decode (SOURCE,'BAL',1,'TX',2), trnxamt desc) as BALANCE,
TRNXAMT
from tx
where acct_id = 123456 
order by date_trnx;

SOU    ACCT_ID DATE_TRNX           TX_MONTH               BALANCE    TRNXAMT
--- ---------- ------------------- ------------------- ---------- ----------
BAL     123456 31.08.2020 00:00:00 01.09.2020 00:00:00        100          0
TX      123456 29.09.2020 00:00:00 01.09.2020 00:00:00         45        -55
TX      123456 30.09.2020 00:00:00 01.09.2020 00:00:00         55         10
BAL     123456 30.09.2020 00:00:00 01.10.2020 00:00:00         55          0
TX      123456 01.10.2020 00:00:00 01.10.2020 00:00:00        155        100
TX      123456 01.10.2020 00:00:00 01.10.2020 00:00:00        175         20
BAL     123456 31.10.2020 00:00:00 01.11.2020 00:00:00        175          0
```

Now everything is ready for a simple `MIN` and `MAX` aggregation grouping by account and month

```
with tx as (
select 'BAL' source, acct_id,  monthend_date  date_trnx, trunc(monthend_date+1,'MM') tx_month, balance, 0 trnxamt from AccountBalanceHistory
union all
select 'TX', acct_id, date_trnx,trunc(date_trnx,'MM') tx_month, trnxamt balance, trnxamt from Transaction
), tx2 as (
select 
SOURCE, ACCT_ID, DATE_TRNX, TX_MONTH,  
sum(BALANCE) over (partition by ACCT_ID,TX_MONTH order by date_trnx, decode (SOURCE,'BAL',1,'TX',2), trnxamt desc) as BALANCE,
TRNXAMT
from tx
where acct_id = 123456)
select acct_id, TX_MONTH, min(BALANCE), max(BALANCE) 
from tx2
group by acct_id, TX_MONTH
order by 1,2;

   ACCT_ID TX_MONTH            MIN(BALANCE) MAX(BALANCE)
---------- ------------------- ------------ ------------
    123456 01.09.2020 00:00:00           45          100
    123456 01.10.2020 00:00:00           55          175
    123456 01.11.2020 00:00:00          175          175
```